# django admin static isn't working

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles, django-settings, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my website on pythonanywhere and everything is working fine except of django admin. It's not showing css (staticfiles).
Here is my static settings (I'm using django 1.8):

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

On pythonanywhere, in static files section I've added:

```
Url: /static/   Directory: /home/username/hypercube/static
```

I've also added this at the end of my urls.py:

```
if True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                   document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think this may help you... https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/

Comment: Does adding a / in URL and /home/erebbit/hypercube/ in Directory helps?

Comment: It helped. Thank you mohammed qudah